# Docker - access container only by specific IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I want to configure my network in Docker which allow to connect to container only by using specific IP.

My problem is that I configured network in my docker-compose file and I can connect to mysql container for example using MySQL Workbench with 172.28.1.2:3306 and also with 127.0.0.1:3306. It's possible to configure that I can connect to that container only by using 172.28.1.2:3306??

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    apache:
        container_name: apache
        build: ./bin/apache
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            backend:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1
        volumes:
            - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html/wordpress/
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        build: ./bin/mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        networks:
            backend:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
        volumes:
            - sql:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
    backend:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
volumes:
    sql:
```

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the `ports:` the container will be inaccessible from outside its specific Docker network.  If you're on the one very specific configuration where the host can directly contact the Docker-private IP addresses, you can't prevent that.  (Since this only works in one very specific configuration, it's usually not useful to specify them.)

So if you have the Dockerfile:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    apache:
        build: ./bin/apache
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    mysql:
        build: ./bin/mysql
        restart: always
        # no ports:
        environment: { as: above }
        volumes:
            - sql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    sql:
```

The `apache` container can connect to `mysql:3306` (without any `expose:` or `ports:` directive).  The host system can connect to `http://localhost:80` to reach the `apache` container but can't directly connect to the `mysql` container (unless it's a native-Linux host and you manually look up the IP address, not recommended).  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has some more information on the container network environment.